# Regex for a extracting a string starting with a particular word and ending with a year

Tags: python, regex, python-re

**INPUT 1:** The string is enclosed CASE NO.: Appeal (civil) 648 of 2007 in between.

**OUTPUT 1:** Appeal (civil) 648 of 2007

**INPUT 2:** The string is enclosed CASE NO.: Appeal (civil) 6408 of 2007 in between.

**OUTPUT 2:** Appeal (civil) 6408 of 2007

I want to extract the string starting with the word CASE NO.(Case Insensitive) and ending with the year being the second occurrence of a number.

I have tried the following code.

```
case_no = re.search(r'(?=Case No)(\w+\W+)*?\b\d{4}\b', contents, re.IGNORECASE)
    if case_no:
        print(case_no.group(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a lazy dot here to match the nearest year occurring after `CASE NO.`:

```py
inp = "The string is enclosed CASE NO.: Appeal (civil) 6408 of 2007 in between."
m = re.search(r'\bCASE NO\.:\s*(.*\b\d{4}\b)', inp)
print(m.group())  # Appeal (civil) 6408 of 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = "The string is enclosed CASE NO.: Appeal (civil) 6408 of 2007 in between."
case_no = re.search(r'(?=Case No)(\w+\W+)*?\d+(\w+\W+)*?\b\d{4}\b', inp, re.IGNORECASE)
print(case_no.group())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).